# require_onceをオブジェクト関数で使いたい

Tags: php

require_onceをオブジェクト関数で使用するにはどうした良いですか?

index.php

```
<?php
    require_once("functions.php")
    $User-> created();
?>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
   class User{
     public $name;
     public $password;
     public function __construct($name , $password) {
      $this ->name = $name;
      $this ->password = $password;
     }
     public function created() {
      print "{$this->name}" ;
      }
   }
   $User = new User ($_POST["name"] , $_POST["pass"]);
   $User-> created();
   ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`require_once`を使って`functions.php`ファイルの`User`クラスを読み込みたいならば、
ご質問のコード`require_once("functions.php")`の後ろにセミコロンを足すことで実現できます。

`User`クラスをオブジェクト化して`created`関数を呼び出したいならば、
下記のコードのように`index.php`の中で`new`キーワードを使ってオブジェクトを作成してください。
そのオブジェクトの関数を呼び出すことで実現できます。

**index.php**

"hoge"と"fuga"は動作確認用のコードですので書き換えてください。

```
<?php
    require_once("functions.php");
    $User = new User ("hoge", "fuga");
    $User-> created();
?>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php
   class User{
     public $name;
     public $password;
     public function __construct($name , $password) {
      $this ->name = $name;
      $this ->password = $password;
     }
     public function created() {
      print "{$this->name}" ;
      }
   }
?>
```